# NotFoundError: Failed to restore from checkpoint or SavedModel at /content/training/ckpt-9:

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am trying to realize this [project](https://github.com/abg3/Smoke-Detection-using-Tensorflow-2.2.git) on Google Colaboratory, but I have been stuck on the same bug  for a while.

Everything was fine until section "27" of the project.
Here is the error I encounter:

---

````
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/py_checkpoint_reader.py in NewCheckpointReader(filepattern)
     95   try:
---> 96     return CheckpointReader(compat.as_bytes(filepattern))
     97   # TODO(b/143319754): Remove the RuntimeError casting logic once we resolve the

RuntimeError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /content/training/ckpt-9

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
6 frames
NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /content/training/ckpt-9

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py in restore(self, save_path, options)
   2338           None, None,
   2339           "Failed to restore from checkpoint or SavedModel at {}: {}".format(
-> 2340               orig_save_path, e.message))
   2341     # Create the save counter now so it gets initialized with other variables
   2342     # when graph building. Creating it earlier would lead to errors when using,

NotFoundError: Failed to restore from checkpoint or SavedModel at /content/training/ckpt-9: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for /content/training/ckpt-9```
````

Comment: Can you please add complete code to the description or colab file you have tried? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: yeah my dear @TFer2, the link of colab file is :
https://github.com/abg3/Smoke-Detection-using-Tensorflow-2.2/blob/master/EfficientDet-D0_Wildfire_Detector.ipynb